# What should I do in a information call from the company of my interest?

Tags: interviewing, management, human-resources

I am a Ph.D candidate going to pass out from my uni and I received a call from a company I adore very much and wish to join. I was told by the HR that this is completely a non-technical information call. This is the email I received

> Thank you for confirming your availability for an informational call with ***********. We have scheduled the call on **********.
>
> Please use this opportunity to get a thorough understanding of the
>   role, the scope of work and know more about the team. You could ask
>   any related questions as well.

Is this kind of informational call common? What kind of questions should I ask?  Does this mean I will be called for a technical interview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations!  The big points you should ask about are about the role and scope (to know if you are interested in this particular position) along with about the team and company

Example role/scope questions:

- What skills will I regularly be using in this position?
- Will I be supervising?
- Hours?

Example team/company questions:

- What are some typical projects this team works on?
- What are some defining characteristics of the corporate culture?
- How large is the team and what is the average experience level?
- What are the prospects for advancement like?

This is a good sign but it doesn't necessarily mean you are going to get a technical interview.  Things can go wrong on either end.  Take advantage of this to get information directly from someone on the inside to make sure this would be a good fit for you.

Good Luck!